# Как у тега <a> убрать визуальные эффекты?

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, как у тега `<a>` убрать цвет, чтобы он выглядел не как ссылка, а как текст или рамка, а не был синего цвета или фиолетовым после нажатия на него

css

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a class="text"><h1>block1</h1></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
a {
  color: #000 !important;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div>
<a class="text"><h1>block1</h1></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте тогда уже полный код для выполнения

Comment: text-decoration: none;

Comment: у автора есть text-decoration: none в коде. не будем дублировать

Comment: использовать `!important` для окрашивания ссылок - непотребство. проблема легко решается через псевдокласс, а `!important` в в стилях - крайняя мера

Comment: да, но перечислять множество псевдоклассов долго и откровенно говоря лень.

Answer (score 21):

Надо прописать для каждого состояния ссылки стиль оформления, используя [псевдоклассы](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/psevdoklassy).
А использовать `!important` надо только в самых крайних случаях.

```css
a.text:active, /* активная/посещенная ссылка */
a.text:hover,  /* при наведении */
a.text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="text"><h1>block1</h1></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо спасибо спасибо но при наведении мне как раз не надо

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛюбимов в таком случае достаточно прописать `a.text:active, a.text {...}`, а для наведения прописать отдельно ` a.text:hover {...}`, если понадобится в будущем. отметьте мой ответ принятым галочкой слева от вопроса, если он вам подходит

Comment: Мне подошел еще первый вариант задать цвет большего мне и не требовалось=) Но вам все равно спасибо!

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛюбимов не вопрос, но тогда следует учесть на будущее, что если всё-таки будет нужда задать какой-то другой цвет для ссылок при наведении, то, например, `a.text:hover { color: green}    a{ color: #000 !important }` не сработает, и придётся прописывать `!important` везде. а это повлечёт за собой вероятные проблемы в виде уродливого трудноподдерживаемого кода

Comment: Спасибо я это прекрасно понимаю и в своем коде я использовал псевдоклассы без использования !important. Я имено не мог решить вопрос изменения цвета обьектов находящихсфя в теге <a>. А вам спасибо за развернутый объект. Я только начал всем этим заниматься и понимаю что скорее всего многое делаю не так. Через пару дней я думаю закончу с сайтом выложу его  и брошу на обозрение на форум буду не против разумной критики от опытных фронтендов.